# Swift async API requests - NSURLSession or ReactiveExtensions?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, nsurlsession, rx-swift

As I am migrating some of the old functionality related to web service calls from synchronous calls to asynchronous - I was curious about the following.

What is the best technology pick?

I am considering between NSURLSession and Reactive Extensions.

In general, I would prefer to go with NSURLSession mainly because of framework support in terms of maintenance. In contrary, I've used Reactive Extensions so far in some other systems written in Scala, and has proven to be quite suited for handling API requests - though I have to say that the concepts were at the beginning harder to understand then just examining the Apple's documentation onto NSURLSession.

What is you experience with this kind of things? What would you recommend, and most importantly, why?

Comment: If you like Rx, go with Rx (RxSwift or ReactiveCocoa). It's great

Comment: Rx is not a technology to solve network related tasks, but NSURLSession is. On the other hand, NSURLSession does not support you in implementing asynchronous patters. A _combination of both_ seems appropriated to solve your problem. There are however, other solutions than Rx which are perfectly suitable in this scenario: Promises and Futures. Rx is quite heave weight and requires a steep learning curve - while futures/promise are simple.